# jquery slideup and down multiple divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

My code is:

### JavaScript:

```
$(".Head").click(function () {
      if ($(".Body").is(":hidden")) {
        $(".Body").slideDown('fast');
      } else {
        $(".Body").slideUp('fast');
      }
    });
```

### HTML:

```
<div class="Head">
Heading
</div>
<div class="Body">
Content
</div>
```

Now my problem is i have multiple div tags in the similar name and format the Head and Body
class is repeated and when i click one Head section it slides up all of them how can i make them slide up and down there particular Body class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close. Here is a jsfiddle which does what you need it to do.

http://jsfiddle.net/Sze8D/

You need to just grab the next body after the heading you clicked by using `.next()`

Answer (score 1):

Try using [$.next()](http://api.jquery.com/next/) like this:

```
$(".Head").click(function () {
    var $targetBody = $(this).next('.Body');
    if ($targetBody.is(":hidden")) {
        $targetBody.slideDown('fast');
    } else {
        $targetBody.slideUp('fast');
    }
});
```

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/vJn8w/

Answer (score 0):

Make your selector more specific; chances are this will entail adding `id` attributes to elements and then using the [jQuery ID selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/). Either give a parent element an `id` attribute...

### HTML

```
<div id="tehParent"><div class="Body"><!-- ... --></div></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#tehParent .Body").slideDown('fast');
```

---

... or give the element itself an `id`:

### HTML

```
<div id="tehBody" class="Body"><!-- ... --></div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$("#tehBody.Body").slideDown('fast');
```

Comment: and what if he has .. emm .. 20 such **head - body** combinations ?

Comment: Can you show more markup? Do they always appear next to each other? Do they always have a common parent... etc. What's the relationship between what is clicked and the elements which should move?